# Did Taiwan support "Hong Kongers" trying to resettle as its president said?

Tags: china, immigration, foreign-policy, refugees, taiwan

[This answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/53604/16047) to *What did Taiwan's president Tsai Ing-wen actually say that it would do for "Hong Kongers"?* says (paraphrased):

> (Taiwan) means to help new settlements of Hong Kong people... Such assistance is currently carried out by voluntary groups, but the Taiwan government would cooperate with them.

**Question:** Ten months and a "[crackdown or two](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-china-56264117)" later, to what extent did Taiwan do so, or do other related things? Have there been resettlements or other assistance with visas and opportunities to leave Hong Kong? Have there been any instances of literal "boat people" reaching shore and given a new place to live?

Comment: Googling something like *Hong Kong refugees Taiwan* shows lots of news stories, although most of them seem to be people travelling by commercial airliner rather than small boat. Examples: https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/jun/22/neither-citizens-nor-foreigners-hongkongers-struggle-to-adapt-to-life-in-taiwan https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2022/5/20/taiwan-delays-scheme-to-help-hong-kongers-over-spying-fears

Answer (score 2):

It is unknown how many Hong Kong refugees are currently in Taiwan, though the [South China Morning Post](https://www.scmp.com/news/hong-kong/politics/article/3019398/taiwan-struggling-deal-influx-hong-kong-protesters-seeking) reported in July that there were up to 60 Hong Kong asylum seekers in Taiwan. The number can't be confirmed, because to date, Taiwan does not have a "refuge law" guiding the process of asylum applications, so rather than approaching the government directly, it is believed that the asylum seekers are assisted by civilian organizations in settling while awaiting the permit allowing resettlement through the channel of formal immigration application, or rerouting to third countries, such as the US and UK.

However, other than the asylum seeker, according to this [article](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2022-01-27/number-of-hong-kongers-moving-to-taiwan-hits-a-record),

> The number of Hong Kong residents moving to Taiwan climbed to a record high, a sign of frustrations over a political crackdown and strict rules to curb the coronavirus.

Some 11,173 Hong Kongers received permits last year to live in Taiwan, up 3.3% from a year earlier, according to new data from the National Immigration Agency in Taipei. **That’s the highest figure in official data dating to 1991**.

Comment: @uhoh Link added.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/asia_pacific/hong-kong-taiwan-immigration-nsl/2021/05/14/354da41a-ad4c-11eb-82c1-896aca955bb9_story.html) in the Washington Post, at least 5 refugees from Hong Kong have received help in Taiwan after they were able to flee.